# How can I remove red line on xml file?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I want to develop jenkins plugin with Eclipse, so I build project with terminal(Ubuntu 16.04). and converted to Eclipse.
but I got a error in `pom.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.jenkins.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}${changelist}</version>
    <packaging>hpi</packaging>
    <properties>
        <revision>1.0</revision>
        <changelist>-SNAPSHOT</changelist>

        <!-- Baseline Jenkins version you use to build the plugin. Users must have this version or newer to run. -->
        <jenkins.version>2.235.1</jenkins.version>
        <java.level>8</java.level>
        <gitHubRepo>jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin</gitHubRepo>    </properties>
    <name>TODO Plugin</name>
    <url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin</url>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Pick up common dependencies for the selected LTS line: https://github.com/jenkinsci/bom#usage -->
                <groupId>io.jenkins.tools.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom-2.235.x</artifactId>
                <version>16</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>structs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-cps</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-job</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-basic-steps</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-durable-task-step</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <!-- If you want this to appear on the plugin site page:
    <developers>
      <developer>
        <id>bhacker</id>
        <name>Bob Q. Hacker</name>
        <email>bhacker@nowhere.net</email>
      </developer>
    </developers> -->

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/${gitHubRepo}.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:${gitHubRepo}.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/${gitHubRepo}</url>
        <tag>${scmTag}</tag>
    </scm>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

this is my pom.xml file. I am trying to build hello world example file(suggested by jenkins). and `<parent>` show red line.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:jar:3.17 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to build parent project for io.jenkins.plugins:example:hpi:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.649 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-08T00:50:56+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

and this is message on console when I run with Maven build on Eclipse.
any idea to solve this problem? I am very new Jenkins, Maven so I need detail explain and solution.

Comment: Have you just run `mvn`? Try `mvn clean install`.

Comment: The error you're receiving in the pom is unrelated to what you're seeing in the console.  Just run a `mvn clean install`